# Flutter sqflite app does not working on real ios device

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sqflite

I have a flutter app using sqflite database. It works perfectly on android emulator and device, also working on ios simulator. on ios real device it works but does not save or retrieve data just static empty UI 
I use xcode 10.1, and ios 11.2.6 on iphone 6 and ios 12.1.4 on iphone 5s.

```
    import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/models/note.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {

    static DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper;    // Singleton DatabaseHelper
    static Database _database;                // Singleton Database

    String noteTable = 'note_table';
    String colId = 'id';
    String colTitle = 'title';
    String colDescription = 'description';
    String colPriority = 'priority';
    String colDate = 'date';

    DatabaseHelper._createInstance(); // Named constructor to create instance of DatabaseHelper

    factory DatabaseHelper() {

        if (_databaseHelper == null) {
            _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._createInstance(); // This is executed only once, singleton object
        }
        return _databaseHelper;
    }

    Future<Database> get database async {

        if (_database == null) {
            _database = await initializeDatabase();
        }
        return _database;
    }

    Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {
        // Get the directory path for both Android and iOS to store database.
        Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String path = directory.path + 'notes.db';

        // Open/create the database at a given path
        var notesDatabase = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
        return notesDatabase;
    }

    void _createDb(Database db, int newVersion) async {

        await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $noteTable($colId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $colTitle TEXT, '
                '$colDescription TEXT, $colPriority INTEGER, $colDate TEXT)');
    }

    // Fetch Operation: Get all note objects from database
    Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getNoteMapList() async {
        Database db = await this.database;

//      var result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $noteTable order by $colPriority ASC');
        var result = await db.query(noteTable, orderBy: '$colPriority ASC');
        return result;
    }

    // Insert Operation: Insert a Note object to database
    Future<int> insertNote(Note note) async {
        Database db = await this.database;
        var result = await db.insert(noteTable, note.toMap());
        return result;
    }

    // Update Operation: Update a Note object and save it to database
    Future<int> updateNote(Note note) async {
        var db = await this.database;
        var result = await db.update(noteTable, note.toMap(), where: '$colId = ?', whereArgs: [note.id]);
        return result;
    }

    // Delete Operation: Delete a Note object from database
    Future<int> deleteNote(int id) async {
        var db = await this.database;
        int result = await db.rawDelete('DELETE FROM $noteTable WHERE $colId = $id');
        return result;
    }

    // Get number of Note objects in database
    Future<int> getCount() async {
        Database db = await this.database;
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> x = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT (*) from $noteTable');
        int result = Sqflite.firstIntValue(x);
        return result;
    }

    // Get the 'Map List' [ List<Map> ] and convert it to 'Note List' [ List<Note> ]
    Future<List<Note>> getNoteList() async {

        var noteMapList = await getNoteMapList(); // Get 'Map List' from database
        int count = noteMapList.length;         // Count the number of map entries in db table

        List<Note> noteList = List<Note>();
        // For loop to create a 'Note List' from a 'Map List'
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            noteList.add(Note.fromMapObject(noteMapList[i]));
        }

        return noteList;
    }

}
```

this code is a tutorial on youtube and it works fine on android and ios simulator only

Comment: Please add the relevant code with your question (Eg: Creating SQLite, insert method etc)

Comment: @MidhunMP i edited the question with included code

Comment: What is the value of `path` in `initializeDatabase`? I think a `/` is missing in there.

Comment: @MidhunMP where can I find it?

Answer (score 6):

I found this answer on github
[github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27844)

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {
    //Get path of the directory for android and iOS.

    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = p.join(databasesPath, 'cards.db');

    //open/create database at a given path
    var cardDatabase = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);

    return cardDatabase;

  }
```

Add package in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path: any
```

Comment: Do we need to remove path_provider and add path dependency?

Answer (score 1):

I run into same issue.
You may use path_provider package but then, for ios, you also have to use path_provider_macos package

```
path_provider: ^1.6.1
path_provider_macos: ^0.0.1
```

I also switched to path package.

Comment: Is that any technical information on this? other than the answer

Answer (score 0):

First remove path_provider from yaml file and add

```
  path: any
```

into your .yaml file. Now in the database helper class add this import

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
```

and create a database path like this one

```
Future<Database> initializedDatabase() async {

var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String path = p.join(directory.toString(),"imo.db");

/// create the database
var notesDatabase = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDatabase);
return notesDatabase;
 }
```