# SQFlite unable to insert into database on iOS 14.3

Tags: ios, flutter, sqflite

I am working on a Flutter app and I am testing on both Android and iOS devices. My app works perfectly on a physical Android device and it works on an iOS device with iOS 13. The problem is that since I updated the iOS device to iOS 14.3, I cannot insert into the database with SQFlite.

**What does work**

- Android devices
- iOS devices with iOS older than 14
- Reading from the database (meaning items that were inserted into the database when the phone was on iOS 13 can successfully be retrieved after updating to iOS 14.3)

**What does not work**

- Inserting into the database on iOS 14.3.

```
await db.transaction((txn) async {
  return await txn.insert(TodoList.TABLENAME, TodoList.toMap(todoList),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
});
```

The app does not provide any error logs and it also does not crash; I can continue to interact with the app. It behaves as if it just disregards the database insert. I've tried a few different things to get it to work but I am at a loss. I appreciate any advice!

This is the first thing I tried: [Flutter sqflite app does not working on real ios device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207234/flutter-sqflite-app-does-not-working-on-real-ios-device)

I also tried a workaround mentioned here (although it may not be relevant to my issue): [Modify schema structure fails on iOS 14](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/525)

**Relevant Code**

Dependencies (Edit: Issue occurs on any SQFlite version, even 1.3.2+2):

```
sqflite: ^1.3.0
path_provider: ^0.4.1
```

Database Class:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import 'package:todo_list/data/todo_list.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  //Create a private constructor
  DatabaseHelper._();

  static const databaseName = 'todos_database.db';
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._();
  static Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      return await initializeDatabase();
    }
    return _database;
  }

  initializeDatabase() async {
    return await openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), databaseName),
        version: 1, onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      // Possible fix for iOS issue (did not work)
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        await db.execute('PRAGMA sqflite -- db_config_defensive_off');
      }

      await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE todos(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, listName TEXT, items TEXT, completed TEXT, count INTEGER, color INTEGER, ordering INTEGER)");
    });
  }

  Future<List<TodoList>> retrieveTodos() async {
    final Database db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query(TodoList.TABLENAME);

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return TodoList(
        id: maps[i]["id"],
        listName: maps[i]["listName"],
        items: maps[i]["items"],
        completed: maps[i]["completed"],
        count: maps[i]["count"],
        color: maps[i]["color"],
        ordering: maps[i]["ordering"],
      );
    });
  }

  insertTodo(TodoList todoList) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db.transaction((txn) async {
      return await txn.insert(TodoList.TABLENAME, TodoList.toMap(todoList),
          conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    });
    //return res;
  }

  updateTodo(TodoList todoList) async {
    final db = await database;

    await db.update(TodoList.TABLENAME, TodoList.toMap(todoList),
        where: "id = ?",
        whereArgs: [todoList.id],
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  }

  deleteTodo(int id) async {
    var db = await database;
    db.delete(TodoList.TABLENAME, where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
  }
}
```

Call to insertToDo:

```
await DatabaseHelper.instance.insertTodo(TodoList(
        listName: listName,
        items: encodedTodo,
        completed: encodedDone,
        count: 0,
        color: _mainColor.value,
        ordering: order));
```

**UPDATE**

Attempted raw SQL query. No change, works fine on Android but not on iOS 14.3.

Insert function with raw query:

```
insertTodo(TodoList todoList) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db.transaction((txn) async {
      return await txn.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO todos(listName, items, completed, count, color, ordering) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
          [
            todoList.listName,
            todoList.items,
            todoList.completed,
            todoList.count,
            todoList.color,
            todoList.ordering
          ]);

      /*await txn.insert(TodoList.TABLENAME, TodoList.toMap(todoList),
          conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);*/
    });
    //return res;
  }
```

Note, I've also tried insert without `transaction`.

```
insertTodo(TodoList todoList) async {
    final db = await database;
      return await db.insert(TodoList.TABLENAME, TodoList.toMap(todoList),
          conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  }
```

Comment: Try updating the package, maybe this would help, as this issue might have been patched. Latest version for sqflite is (1.3.2+2)

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention I had already tried this.

Comment: Oh then why do you still have the old version motioned in the question? Please update your question with the versions that you are currently using.

Comment: Did you try to use raw SQL queries? It might be a problem in the orm. If you want help in doing that check this [readme](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/README.md) file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give the raw SQL query a try and give an update on how it goes.

Comment: Oh well, raw SQL query didn't make a difference but it was worth a shot.

Comment: Hmmm, try updating flutter. As a last resort, try to create a new empty flutter app or making sure you followed all the steps mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/how_to.md), just to rule out the possibility of something wrong with your setup.

Comment: @amabe any update on this?

Comment: @amabe try to change `if (_database == null) {` to `if (_database == null || !(database?.isOpen ?? false)) {`

Comment: What fixed it was restarting the phone again after the update to iOS 14.3